# PHP: can't decode JSON from string

Tags: php, json

I wrote this function to build a JSON-style string:

```
function createJsonFromResponse($response_json)
{
    // output json
    $output_json = '[';

    // number of steps
    $num_steps = count($response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']);
    //echo $num_steps;

    // fill the json
    for($i = 0; $i<$num_steps; $i++)
    {
        // start parenthesis
        $output_json .= '{';

        // start latitude
        $output_json .= '"start_lat":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['start_location']['lat'] . ',';

        // start longitude
        $output_json .= '"start_lng":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['start_location']['lng'] . ',';

        // end latitude
        $output_json .= '"end_lat":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['end_location']['lat'] . ',';

        // end latitude
        $output_json .= '"end_lng":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['end_location']['lng'] . ',';

        // step length
        $output_json .= '"step_length":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['distance']['value'] . ',';

        // html instruction
        $output_json .= '"instruction":"' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['html_instructions'] . '"';

        // closure parenthesis
        $output_json .= '}';


        // insert comma if required
        if($i != $num_steps-1)
            $output_json .= ',';

    }

    $output_json .= ']';
    return $output_json;
}
```

Then, I gave the output string from this function to another one. This second function performs this simple action:

```
$steps_dec = json_decode($steps_txt,true);
```

where `$steps_txt` is the string I produced previously.
Anyway, I testes that the output of `json_decode` is **NULL**, while everything work if, in the function producing string, I comment the line adding string field.
It seems to like only numeric field.

can you spot my error?

thanks.

Comment: mistake #1: building your own json. never do that. build a native data structure (e.g array), then `json_encode()` it. You've probably introduced JS syntax errors by dumping raw html into the json text.

Comment: No reason to encode JSON yourself. Just create a `new stdClass()` or assoc `array()` and give it the properties you want. Then use `json_encode`. It's likely you're creating malformed JSON.

Comment: I agree with Marc B and CollinD, but if you want to know what is wrong, you'd have to inspect the output first, check it with JSONLint or whatever, and based on that track down where the error is.

Comment: See what PHP tells you:  `$steps_dec = json_decode($steps_txt,true); if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) { die(json_last_error_msg()); }`

Comment: thank you. your suggestion to create an array first and a JSON then worked for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest json in php

```
$myJson = array('numbers' => array(1, 2, 3));

echo json_encode($myJson);
```